# How to call StorageFile.OpenReadAsync in C++/winrt?

Tags: c++-winrt, win2d

In my continuing efforts to load a collection of .svg files in C++/winrt I'm encountering a mysterious link error. I'd like to try using CanvasSvgDocument.ReadAsync(resourceCreator, filestream). To get there it is first necessary to get the stream from the StorageFile, and this would appear to be the way to do it (nextFile, a StorageFile, is already loaded in this example). This is of course within a method defined as an IAsyncAction. I'll list the #includes and namespaces from the top of the file.

```
#include "winrt/Windows.ApplicationModel.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Storage.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Storage.Streams.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Storage.Search.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.UI.Core.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.h"
#include "pch.h"

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::Storage;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Provider;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Search;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Streams;
```

Here is the problematic call:

```
IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType fileStream = co_await nextFile.OpenReadAsync();
```

That produces a link error that I'll put in below. It doesn't matter whether or not I try the fully qualified name of the fileStream result:

winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams::IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType fileStream = co_await nextFile.OpenReadAsync();

either way I get this link error:

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: struct
>   winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation
>   __thiscall winrt::impl::consume_Windows_Storage_Streams_IRandomAccessStreamReference::OpenReadAsync(void)const "
>   (?OpenReadAsync@?$consume_Windows_Storage_Streams_IRandomAccessStreamReference@UIStorageFile@Storage@Windows@winrt@@@impl@winrt@@QBE?AU?$IAsyncOperation@UIRandomAccessStreamWithContentType@Streams@Storage@Windows@winrt@@@Foundation@Windows@3@XZ)
>   referenced in function "public: struct
>   winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction __thiscall
>   AppEngine::ResourceManager::LoadSvgResources$_ResumeCoro$2(struct
>   winrt::Microsoft::Graphics::Canvas::UI::Xaml::CanvasControl)"
>   (?LoadSvgResources$_ResumeCoro$2@ResourceManager@AppEngine@@QAE?AUIAsyncAction@Foundation@Windows@winrt@@UCanvasControl@Xaml@UI@Canvas@Graphics@Microsoft@6@@Z)

I've also tried using auto as the result type, no luck. What is the right way to obtain a stream using OpenReadAsync() in C++/winrt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are apparently compiling with [precompiled headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/y-precompiled-headers) enabled (hinted to by the `#include "pch.h"` directive). When doing so, the header used to generate the precompiled header **must** be included on the first non-empty, non-comment line in the compilation unit consuming it.

The [/Yu (Use Precompiled Header File)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/yu-use-precompiled-header-file) documentation has the relevant information:

> The compiler treats all code occurring before the .h file as precompiled. It skips to just beyond the #include directive associated with the .h file, uses the code contained in the .pch file, and then compiles all code after `filename`.

In other words, all your includes preceding the `#include "pch.h"` directive are ignored. Since C++/WinRT is a header-only library, this will eventually result in linker errors.

To fix the issue

- Move the `#include "pch.h"` directive to the very top of the file, or
- Replace the `#include` directive with the [/FI (Name Forced Include File)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fi-name-forced-include-file) compiler option on the relevant compilation units, or
- Disable use of precompiled headers.

Comment: Wow, great answer, thanks. Putting pch.h at the top solves the link error problem very nicely and the LoadAsync apparently is loading svgs. Still can't get the loaded svgs to draw in the CanvasControl's drawing session, but I'll put up another question about that.